# Clear the back stack using fragments

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

These lines of code are used in a fragment. The aim is to go to the login activity from this fragment but It does not work

```
 logoutButton.Click += (s, a) => {
  ViewModel.Logout();
  //var intent = LoginActivity.CreateIntent(Context);
  var intent = new Intent(Context, typeof(LoginActivity));
  intent
   .PutExtra("ViewModelType", typeof(LoginViewModel).ToString())
   .AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.ClearTask | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
  StartActivity(intent);
 };
```

Comment: Logout is a method I created it on a ViewModel used in this fragment

Comment: StartActivity is built-in in the Fragment class in Xamarin Native

"public virtual void StartActivity(Intent intent);"

Comment: Guys, regarding lowercase and uppercases, my question is about Xamarin Native. I using C# and not Java.

Comment: If you use Visual Studio Android App(Xamarin), what is the Context? Normally, we use `this`. Comment the intent.PutExtra......, only use `var intent = new Intent(Context, typeof(LoginActivity));  StartActivity(intent);` to check you could start the activity or not. You could provide more code about LoginViewModel, LoginActivity for me to test.